# How to set the position of ImageView after getting x and y postion on finger touch in iphone

Tags: ios, ipad, touch, imageview

I am making an ipad app in which I have tableView with custom it works fine but I want that when user clicks on add button in custom cell then it should get the position x and y of that button and then set the imageView to the center of that button.

I have searced code it gets points but how to add make this for cell.addButton as cell is custom.

```
        [cell.imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonActionOne:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Here is the code for touch

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *rec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
   [cell.addButton addGestureRecognizer:rec];
    [rec release];
```

But in this way it does not call the method which is on cell.addButton imageButtonAction.

Comment: Why use a UIButton AND UITapGestureRecognizer on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from you , you need to set an image in a UIButton upon tap.

If you added the UITapGestureRecognizer you removed the default tap recognition and now only this would work:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *rec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
[cell.addButton addGestureRecognizer:rec];
[rec release];
```

You should remove the above code and only set this:

```
[cell.addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

where the **imageButtonAction:** is :

```
- (void )imageButtonAction:(UIButton *) b
{
 [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

If you want to add an image next to the button let's say in the left of the button then the function should look like this:

```
- (void )imageButtonAction:(UIButton *) b
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[b superview]; 
 NSInteger imgWidth = 50;
 UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(b.frame.origin.x - imgWidth,b.frame.origin.y,imgWidth,b.frame.size.height)];
img.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell addSubview:img];
[img release];

}


       UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
UIImageView *backimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,312,105)];

//If you want to do this set interaction enabled.
backimage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
backimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"popupj.png"];



tab1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[tab1 setFrame:CGRectMake(-1,2,293,58)];
[tab1 setTitle:@"Record Video" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tab1 addTarget:self action:@selector(tab1Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[tab1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popuptab1j.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backimage addSubview:tab1];
```

now i am adding button to imageView but it does not get clicked

Comment: no i do not want to add image on button i want to show separate UIImageView beside button

Comment: you want to add the image next to the button? Please be more specific so we can understand what you need.

Comment: yes i want that when cell button is clicked then it should a new image beside cell image button

Comment: you are again seting image to the button which clicked not the new UIImageView

Comment: how to give this new image to the align of the x axis of the button clicked

Comment: you just set the CGRectMake(b.frame.origin.x,your_y,width,height); You should have the image aligned to the button's x.

Comment: yes i have added image but problem is that i am adding button to that imageView but does not get clicked

Comment: so you want to add a uibutton instead of an uiimageview?, please be give more information because I'm getting confused.

Comment: Okay if you want to do that you should set the UIImageView property img.userInteractionEnabled = YES because by default is set to NO so no subview can be touched.

Answer (score 0):

For UIButton you can use directly button function

```
-(IBAction) imageButtonAction:(id) sender
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
  //[btn setimage:[UIImage imagenamed:dimagename];
  UIImageview *backimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:btn.frame];
  [cell addSubview:backimage];
}
```

Comment: i am not saying about button please check the question first i want that when user click on button it should get button position and make new imageView to show image beside button thanks